# Save Files in Local Database in C#

Tags: c#

I wanna know how to save File in Database 
I made DB like this

[image]

But I don't know how to use this type of format and Maybe this way is false

Comment: Yes this way is not recommended.You can store your files in your local folder and store just the filename in your db and when to retrieve this file you can append the file name in the local folder url.

Comment: I think it's Good way but this way has some cons and pros

Comment: cons : When the file delete in Computer we can't use it
and We can't Move the File with DB to another PC

Answer (score 0):

You should store the file contents in a varbinary field in the database. The way of doing this depends on the tools you are using.

If you use Entity Framework for example, then you should use a byte array to represent the content of the file.